# How can I read a value I have just written in a serial port (Python)?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to write data in the serial port and then read the same data. But it only returns a blank page when I try to read the data. How can I fix this issue?

My code

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem14302', 115200, timeout = 1)

print ("Writing: ")
ser.write(b'somedata\r\n')

time.sleep(2)

read_val = ser.readline().decode()
print(read_val) # returns a blank line
```

The expected result: `"somedata"`

The actual result: `" "`

Comment: where is time.sleep(2) ment to be? between ser.write and read_val?

Comment: Yes. I just edited it. Thank you

Comment: is this on a localhost? or really on a  usb or a modem?

Comment: @Matthijs990 it is on a USB

Comment: does it need to use serial? and did you try to make an new serial.Serial variable?

Comment: A serial port is for a communication link.  It is not a storage device.

Comment: if it is an communication link why dont you just use socket?

Comment: If you're expecting echo or loopback, then you need to clarify your question.